# Angularjs ui typeahead to focus after select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

You can even see the problem in the angular ui's demo.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Typeahead once you select a suggested value loses focus on the input prevent you from submitting it. How do I get it to focus on the input after a suggested value is clicked upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line into typeahead.js:148 select function.

```
element[0].focus();
```

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XB5ybI?p=preview